# Error while installating EPPlus package offline on package manager console in visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, installation, epplus, nuget-package-manager-console

Error message -
Install -Package : Exception  'System.AggeratteException' thrown when trying to add source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'
Please verify all your online package are available.
One or more errors occurred.
Unable to load the service index for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
An error occurred while sending the request.
The underlying connection was closed. an unexpected error occurred on a send.
Unable to read data from transport connection: an existing connection was forcibly closed by remote host.

Comment: Hi Amit, is your issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

Please [download](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/) the related `.nupkg` file to your local machine and add/set the corresponding **[package source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#package-sources)** in VS > Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > Package Sources, then install it offline by using package manager console.